# achartengine - taking an integral?

Tags: achartengine, integral

I'm using achartengine to display real-time data. Does anyone know if it's possible to take an integral of the graph displayed by using some nice methods of achartengine? Or do I have to resort to my approximations with rectangles?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you should refine the question a little bit. What does it mean "to take an integral of the graph"?

Comment: Dan taking a integral of a function(graph) is pretty well defined. The question would rather be, would you like a graphical representation for the integral? (This is some times done as filling the area between the x-axis and the function.) This is possible to do in achartengine, probably with rectangle approximation. I don't believe there is a "fill" function. If you want some sort of mathematical definition of the integral the answer is that achartengine is not a math library and don't have any functions for such problems.

Comment: I want a numerical value for the total area under the curve. I guess I'll have to do my own approximation, but I thought it was worth a shot to find out if achartengine has a function built-in :) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no way to achartengine to calculate the integral. To get a number value for the integral you would need to either do a approximation you self or if you have a well defined function use some sort of mathematical library.

Depending on what sort of data you have there are several ways to do the approximation, if you got a equidistant dataset with a reasonable resolution just summing them up will give you a simple approximation.